# System.AccessViolationException with SQL Unittest in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing

I want to implement unit tests with Visual Studio for a SQL Server application.

But when I want to run the tests in the Test Explorer, I get the following error message.

Because I can't find any solution for this, I hope someone else can help me :)

> Message: Initialization method
>
> ModulverbinderDB_UnitTest.TestISOValidateStepV2_MockError.TestInitialize threw exception. System.AccessViolationException: a: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt..
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> SNINativeManagedWrapperX64.SNIOpenSyncExWrapper(SNI_CLIENT_CONSUMER_INFO& pClientConsumerInfo, IntPtr& ppConn)
> SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIOpenSyncEx(ConsumerInfo consumerInfo, String constring, IntPtr& pConn, Byte[] spnBuffer, Byte[] instanceName, Boolean fOverrideCache, Boolean fSync, Int32 timeout, Boolean fParallel, Int32 transparentNetworkResolutionStateNo, Int32 totalTimeout, Boolean isAzureSqlServerEndpoint, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, SQLDNSInfo cachedDNSInfo)
> SNIHandle.ctor(ConsumerInfo myInfo, String serverName, Byte[] spnBuffer, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int32 timeout, Byte[]& instanceName, Boolean flushCache, Boolean fSync, Boolean fParallel, TransparentNetworkResolutionState transparentNetworkResolutionState, Int32 totalTimeout, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, SQLDNSInfo cachedDNSInfo)
> TdsParserStateObject.CreatePhysicalSNIHandle(String serverName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]& instanceName, Byte[] spnBuffer, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async, Boolean fParallel, TransparentNetworkResolutionState transparentNetworkResolutionState, Int32 totalTimeout, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, String cachedFQDN)
> TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType, String certificate, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, Boolean useOriginalAddressInfo, Boolean disableTnir)
> SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)
> SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
> SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
> SqlInternalConnectionTds.ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
> SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
> SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
> SqlDatabaseTestService.CreateConnectionContext(ConnectionContextElement config)
> SqlDatabaseTestService.OpenExecutionContext()
> SqlDatabaseTestClass.InitializeTest()
> TestISOValidateStepV2_MockError.TestInitialize() line 24

Some solutions mentioned an inconsistency with x86 vs. x64 but my host VM and also Visual Studio are both x64

Comment: Your questions needs more details. Please add some code, and context. This is also a good place to start https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I didn't found the answer for this, I guess it was a problem with the option 'deploy before run the tests' and a missing permission. My solution: I created a new test project without this option and this worked. In my case this is an option because I deploy the actual scheme over a pipeline.